# Dark Theme for C++ application on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows-10, themes

I am using the application Qalculate on Windows 10. Qalculate is written in C++. I would like to apply a dark theme, possibly contributing to the Github project.

[GitHub](https://github.com/Qalculate)

[GitHub Libraries](https://github.com/Qalculate/libqalculate)

[Website](https://qalculate.github.io/)

[Screenshots](https://qalculate.github.io/screenshots.html)

Here is what the app currently looks like on my system:

[image: Current Look]

The screenshots on the Qalculate website show a dark theme: 

[image: Desired look]

I've contacted the primary developer Hanna-kn about how to apply the dark theme. This was her reply:

> You can either add environment variable (in advanced system properties) GTK_THEME with value Adwaita:dark, or create a file named settings.ini, in folder C:\Program Files\Qalculate\share\gtk-3.0 or C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\gtk-3.0, with the following contents
>
> [Settings]
>   gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme=true

It appears that she is using Linux and the process to apply a theme to a specific application in Windows 10 is different than Linux. 

**What code would need to be added to the Github project to allow a dark theme? Or is there another application that would allow an application specific dark theme in Windows 10.**

**Note:** 
Dark theme is already turned on in the Windows 10 settings:
[image: Win 10 settings screenshot]

Comment: What makes you think she's using Linux? The supplied path is definitely windows ...

Comment: The supplied path is Windows, but the gtk settings did not work. When I started researching gtk and windows 10 dark theme, I found results like this: https://github.com/B00merang-Project/Windows-10-Dark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developer Hanna-kn updated her code to allow a dark theme.
Before and After code here:

```
https://github.com/Qalculate/qalculate-gtk/commit/d16c0f424d5bb71dd6a69291d1972b45a2b84f4a
```