# Windows GUI: Can I access the "modern ui" from C++?

Tags: c++, c, user-interface

I am trying to find an answer to a simple question: Can I use the modern UI - that you see in Windows 10 a lot, which is affected by the dark theme too - from C/C++?

I know that the Win32 API windows are not affected by the dark theme, at least for the most part. I have also not found a definitive clue if .NET Windows Forms is affected and UWP uses this odd C++ subset called CX? I am a little confused.

Basically, I just want to pick the right API to design my GUI with the modern UI elements that are commonly used in Windows 10. One of the reasons is that these controls are properly made accessible already - something which other GUI frameworks might actually lack. (I am visually impaired myself and thus do rough testing with NVDA since most of my friends are reliant on these tools.)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53501268/win10-dark-theme-how-to-use-in-winapi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61548093/dark-theme-for-c-application-on-windows-10  https://github.com/ysc3839/win32-darkmode

Answer (score 3):

The *"modern"* UI framework in Windows (which never got a name) was initially only available to applications targeting the Universal Windows Platform (UWP). Later it was made available to classic Desktop applications by way of [XAML islands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/xaml-islands). Later still it was decided to decouple the UI framework from the OS, so that changes can ship independent of OS updates. This is what became [WinUI 2](https://microsoft.github.io/microsoft-ui-xaml/about.html). With WinUI 3 it is planned to be fully decoupled, making the UI immediately available to classic Desktop applications.

The entire API surface is exposed as Windows Runtime types. While you can interact with those types at the ABI level (which is what the [WRL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/wrl/windows-runtime-cpp-template-library-wrl) does) it is more convenient to use what is coined a *language projection*. Initially, that was C++/CX, a non-standard language extension implemeneted by Microsoft's compiler, which was later superseded by [C++/WinRT](https://aka.ms/cppwinrt), a language projection implemented in Standard C++.

So yes, it is possible to use the new UI framework in a classic Desktop application from C++. Though it has to be noted, that C++/WinRT is still not on par with C++/CX when it comes to IDE integration, and - especially - XAML authoring and binding. Still possible, but it is occasionally more tedious.

Answer (score 1):

Use the WinUI API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/
Note: you can use that with c++, not with c.

Comment: That's incorrect. WinUI uses the Windows Runtime, which has the same [two language-level requirements as COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/the-component-object-model): The ability to create structures of pointers and the ability to call functions through pointers. C perfectly meets those requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I guess all you need is to enable visual styles. By default Win32 app will look like Windows 98/2000 GUI. To switch window borders to WinXP/7/10 style, you need to add manifest file with simple contents and initialize Common Controls library (comctl32.dll) with `InitCommonControls()` or `InitCommonControlsEx()`. See the following articles:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/58606/How-do-you-get-XP-visual-styles-manifest-to-work-o

In short you need to do 3 steps:

1. Add comctl32.lib to your project;
2. Call `InitCommonControls();` (or `InitCommonControlsEx`) in `WinMain`;
3. Embed manifest file or include a file with `.manifest` extension and same name like your `.exe`. See `Manifest Tool` entry in Visual Studio project properties (Additional Manifest Files).

Sample manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<assemblyIdentity
    version="1.0.0.0"
    processorArchitecture="*"
    name="CompanyName.ProductName.YourApplication"
    type="win32"
/>
<description>Application Description</description>
<dependency>
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity
    type="win32"
    name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
    version="6.0.0.0"
    processorArchitecture="*"
    publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
    language="*"
/>
```

Comment: Thank you! I attempted to do test this on a demo application but it keeps resetting my manifest. I should note, I am compiling via command line. Code: https://gist.github.com/IngwiePhoenix/91cbf839f74ee448d5e4433b18dc8abd

Comment: Try with predefined .manifest file and without `#pragma`. I guess your app is compiled 32-bit?

Comment: No, 64bit using cl.exe directly. I usually use VSCode. Going to give this idea a try.

Comment: Tried again, now PowerShell is telling me about a side-by-side config not being correct. I am assuming this would refer to the manifest. It suggests using `sxstrace.exe`, but it works quite differently from the UNIX `strace` so I'll have to poke more.

Comment: Compile it as 32-bit and change `processorArchitecture="x86"` instead of `"*"`.

Comment: Enabling visual styles is not the same thing as using the *"modern"* UI stack.

Comment: @IInspectable It is not the same but will have at least partial effect.

Comment: @i48 Enabling visual styles pertains strictly to the classic Windows common controls. It has no effect whatsoever on the use of the modern UI stack, introduced in Windows 8. That's a completely disjoint UI framework implementation, that doesn't share anything with the classic Windows common controls. Opting in to version 6 of the common controls has thus no effect, not even a *"partial effect"*.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to use C in a real modern UI then your best option is to use Web Technologies, because a "Modern UI" is basically using Web Technologies.

**Modern UI in C**

- Windows - [WebView control for Windows Forms and WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webview)
- Cross-Platform - [WebUI - Use Any Web Browser As GUI](https://github.com/alifcommunity/webui)
- Cross-Platform - [Cross-platform WebView library](https://github.com/webview/webview)

Comment: The question is asking about Windows' native UI. This is an answer to a different question.

Comment: He said "modern UI" and not "native UI". On top of that, I provided "WPF" which is Windows native.

Comment: The question is tagged C and C++. Not sure how you'd use WPF from C or C++.

Comment: You can easily use WPF in C, and C++, and C#, and all other languages supported in .Net. Please remove the non-fair downvote. Thank you.

Comment: You cannot use WPF from C nor C++. If that is news to you, then you shouldn't be attempting to answer questions asking about native programming.

Comment: This is straight from the article you linked to: *"WPF APIs are managed code, but most existing Win32 programs are written in unmanaged C++. **You cannot call WPF APIs from a true unmanaged program.**"* And that's just how things are. You cannot use WPF from C nor C++. If you feel strongly that the two down-votes are unfair, take it to [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Right next to your quote: "_However, by using the /clr option with the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler, you can create a mixed managed-unmanaged program where you can seamlessly mix managed and unmanaged API calls_". That means it's possible to do, while you are talking like it is not possible to do at all... It's okay the downvote, but please correct your information.

Comment: It is not possible, **at all**, to access the WPF from native code. ***NOT AT ALL.*** *"Using the `/clr` option"* means that you are no longer using C++. You're using C++/CLI, a Microsoft-specific language extension that can create mixed-mode assemblies, containing both managed and unmanaged code. Even with a mixed-mode assembly, you cannot access WPF APIs from unmanaged code. In essence: It is ***impossible*** to use the WPF from unmanaged code.

Comment: Okay. I will do a serious test and search to know what's going on.